# React native svg android error: requireNativeComponent RNSVGCIrcle

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

Currently I have an error on Android ([see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obLUW.jpg)).

On iOS there is no error, but it isn't rendered.

RN: 0.61

RNSVG: 11.0.1

```
// The code is simple (just for test the lib)
<Svg width ={10} height={10) viewPort="0 0 10 10">
    <Circle width={9} height={9} fill="#fff" />
</Svg>
```

Comment: hey, if you have any prob to use SVG , then you can check this website https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg and try to read document and manually installation.

Comment: you probably need to re-sync project with gradle files for android and perform a pod installation for ios.